# Difficulty replacing "a" letters from user imputed char word with user imputed replacement letter in C language

Tags: c, loops, input, replace, letter

I apologize if a similar question was answered before but since I'm a first grade programming student I don't really catch up with this C language and so couldn't find my answer.

The result is that I want the user to input a word for ex.: "aleksandras" and after then input a letter say "g" to replace all "a" letters in that word.
I've tried 'debugging' but no result since to me everything looks like it should work as I want it to (you will notice a lot of 'printf's that's basically how I did it).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char zodis[20];

printf("Ivesk 20 raidziu zodi: ");
scanf("%s", zodis);

int zodzioIlgis = strlen(zodis);

char naujasSim[1];

printf("Ivesk raide, kuri pakeis 'a' raides: ");
scanf("%s", naujasSim);
printf("Ivedei: %s \n", naujasSim);

for(int i = 0; i <= zodzioIlgis; i++){

    if(zodis[i] == 'a'){

        zodis[i] = *naujasSim;

        printf("'if' ivyko \n");

    }
    printf("prasibegau\n");
}

printf("Pakoreguotas zodis: %s", zodis);
}
```

I did notice debugging that when say user inputs "aleksandras" the loop ignores the first letter "a" which is supposed to be noticed at the very least but `printf("'if' ivyko \n");` doesn't happen at that point. Also it seems that loop doesn't even start if I type `int zodzioIlgis = strlen(zodis);` right before the loop because `printf("prasibegau\n");` doesn't print. Why so?

To summarize my current code doesn't replace the letters I want it to better yet it just 'deletes' the word from the var which then prints nothing basically.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain why isn't the replacement working as well as regarding my debugging questions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `char naujasSim[1];` That cannot store any string except the empty one because strings have a NUL terminator. Even a single letter string requires two bytes. The result of any such buffer overflow is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kaylum oh I haven't tried `char *naujasSim = "";` which apparently solves my problem, thanks!

Comment: What? No, that's not right either. In fact, that is arguably worse. `""` is a string literal and writing to it is also undefined behaviour. Note that Undefined Behaviour sometimes appears to "work" but can blow up at any time. Do this: `char naujasSim[2]`. But be aware that this will also cause problems if the user enters more than one letter.

Comment: @kaylum I think I get what you've meant by "strings have a NUL terminator" now, haha. That was obvious and I've blown it. But in case of  `char naujasSim[2]` the program now replaces the "a" letters with question marks in a box. Why is that?